# TSQL case statement with multiple when values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to do something like this? (This is pseudo code)

```
      CASE(@P1) 
        WHEN 'a' or 'd' or 'z' THEN 1
        WHEN 'b' or 't' THEN 2
        ELSE 0
```

The idea being that I can check multiple values that should return the same value. i.e. 'a' returns 1 and 't' returns 2

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  What's wrong with 5 lines of code?

Comment: Because in my real world task it is more like 50 lines and the more lines the more likely there will be mistakes. So I am trying to consolidate and simplify.

Comment: Then show us the real task and maybe we can help you.  It's always better to ask your actual question rather than a paraphrase that you think will get you close to the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
select CASE WHEN @P1 in ('a', 'd', 'z') THEN 1
            WHEN @P1 in ('b', 't') THEN 2
            ELSE 0 
       END
from your_table
```

or

```
select CASE WHEN @P1 = 'a' or @P1 = 'd' or @P1 = 'z' THEN 1
            WHEN @P1 = 'b' or @P1 = 't' THEN 2
            ELSE 0 
       END
from your_table
```